# Loading CSV data table as Vector layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, import, vector-layer

This might be a simple problem, but how does one load a simple two-column CSV with no associated geometric data?

I have given a couple of go's via `QgsVectorlayer`[delimited text, spatialite] types - but none seem to work.

for example:

```py
theMinistryOf = ':\...\sillyWalks.csv'
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setDatabase(theMinistryOf)
uri.setDataSource('','','')
notQuiteSillyEnough = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), 'skip_step_slide', 'spatialite')
```

or:

```py
uri = theMinistryOf+'?delimiter=%s' % (",")
sillyWalks = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'sillyWalks', "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sillyWalks)
```

This need is easily fulfilled manually by selecting the load vector layer, but programmatically?

Can a CSV data table be loaded via PyQGIS without geometry?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following snippet works for me:

```py
uri = "file:///C:/testdata/somecsv.csv?delimiter=%s" % (";")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'New CSV','delimitedtext')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

For reference, if you wanted to add it with geometry:

```py
uri = "file:///C:/testdata/somecsv.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (";", "x", "y")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'New CSV','delimitedtext')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Most importantly, make sure the correct delimiter has been specified!

Comment: I have to give you points for posting so quick with responses which indeed work.  But I have figured out another solution - also posed for others references.

Answer (score 5):

Should not have supposed that `'ogr'` wouldn't be able.

```py
someTableLayer = QgsVectorLayer(ministryOf.csv, 'sillyWalks', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(someTableLayer)
```