# Importing shapefiles using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to import a .shp file and CSV file so that I can join data. I have written below code in Python console within QGIS.  For `Layer.isvalid()`, I am getting False. I am using QGIS 3 and on Windows 7. I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Since I am using Python console inside QGIS do I need to set environment variables?

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer("file:///C:Test/t1_2013_06_tract/t1_2013_06_tract.shp","BuildingLayer","ogr")

layer.isValid()
```

Comment: If that is for a shapefile, simply the path should be enough (i.e. `layer=QgsVectorLayer("C:Test/t1_2013_06_tract/t1_2013_06_tract.shp","BuildingLayer","ogr")`

Comment: @Joseph and in case of csv Files I tried above by replacing t1_2013_06_tract.shp by ca_tracts_pop.csv it is still showing invalid

Comment: Your csv path will need to include additional information as to how QGIS should read it (i.e. if you want to load it as vector layer with geometries, you would need to define specific parameters). This post should help: [How to load a data table as a 'vector layer' using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133537/how-to-load-a-data-table-as-a-vector-layer-using-pyqgis)