# Load layers for viewing in QGIS 3 from delimited text

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, python-3

I am trying to use part of a script to add points from a delimited text file, however, when I use it the layers are not loaded on the screen and not saved in the path indicated as .shp

```
import os
import qgis.core

indir = '/home/leo/Área de Trabalho/sle/'
outdir = '/home/leo/Área de Trabalho/sle/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(indir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file).replace('\\', '/')
            filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]
            uri = 'file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&decimal=%s' % (fullname, 'EPSG:4326', ',', 'field2', 'field1', '.')
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'pontos_' + str(filename), 'delimitedtext')
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, "pontos_" + str(file) + ".shp", "utf-8", layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

when I do:

```
print(layer)
<QgsMapLayer: 'pontos_caminho_partículas_3' (delimitedtext)>
```

In this case, I want to read several .txt files, with coordinates and add these points as shape in QGIS. I am using QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Please use translation software so that your question is posted in English.

Comment: Ty for the tip!

Comment: Please take a look at the [following thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133537/how-to-load-a-data-table-as-a-vector-layer-using-pyqgis), it might answer your question.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the txt file as text in your question, for example top 5 rows including header

Comment: Yes, but it's not working