# Importing multiple CSV files in QGIS 3.18 with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, csv, import, batch

I have a folder `C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/Test`, where there's multiple CSVs in it. I'm trying to import all CSVs into QGIS at once. I've tried to modify (the encoding part) the method from
[Loading Multiple CSV Files into QGIS 2.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212910/loading-multiple-csv-files-into-qgis-2-10)

The final code I used is: (It grabs all the files in the folder but appears empty)

```py
import glob, os

path_to_csv = "C:\\Users\\MyPC\\Desktop\\Test" 

os.chdir(path_to_csv)  

for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?encoding=%s&?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("UTF-8", ";", "longtitude", "latitude")
    name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

I thought I might as well use what [the guidebook says](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#loading-layers) and import a *"single"* csv into QGIS just in case something was wrong from the beginning, and yes, it still grabs an empty files.

The code I use:

```py
uri = "file:///C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/Test/test.csv?encoding={}&?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}&crs={}".format("UTF-8", ",", "Longtitude", "Latitude", "espg:4326")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Name", "delimitedtext")
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is just a tiny thing wrong, you forgot to connect your *'path_to_csv'* and *'fname'* with `'//'`

instead of:

```py
uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?encoding=%s&?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("UTF-8", ";", "longtitude", "latitude")
```

it might be:

```py
uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + '//' + fname + "?encoding=%s&?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("UTF-8", ";", "longtitude", "latitude")
```

Also you can create your *uri* with [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), like this

```py
uri = "file:///" + os.path.abspath(fname) + "?encoding=%s&?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("UTF-8", ";", "longtitude", "latitude")
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to implement your method and try it again. But it seems like the changes doesn't affect the result. I'll try to describe the problem here a bit more. 
The code seems to grab the files in the folder, which are listed in the Layer panel, while a warning sign appears claiming the sources are missing.(Layer data source could not be found) That's the point I'm very confused since the code certainly found the folder's location otherwise all the csv fils should not appears. :(

Comment: Can you please show your csv files? Or share a piece of it?

Comment: I'll put the short demo file with 3 species in it in the following link. Since I'm using Traditional Chinese, the only keyword you need is '經度' and '緯度' in the attribute table, which represents the X and Y field. And assuming the given files are in a folder '  C:\\Users\\MyPC\\Desktop\\Test '

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ocx2vnzkQCUgRXAB9_9_CObnnmrl2YJl?usp=sharing

Comment: I just checked your csv files, I think they do not have lat/long in it (Sorry I can not read Chinese), do not they? Therefore, you can not load them as a vector layer with a location, however, you can do it simply as a table: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/133538/99589

Comment: Sorry I might get you confused but the '經度' and '緯度' in the table represents the lat/long. In my original post I modified it into lat/long but in fact I code it as
'''
uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?encoding=%s&?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % ("UTF-8", ";", "經度", "緯度")
'''

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool QGIS plugin that does so. Its name is [CSV Batch Import](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/csv_batch_import/).

It allows browsing for a CSV files directory. Then recursively import all CSV files inside that directory as layers in QGIS.